# why do i get a null pointer exception when i call the constructor of a another class?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

```
case "Login":
        try {
            restoreUserInfo();
            String email = textf1.getText();
            String password = new String(jpass1.getPassword());
            if (hm.containsKey(email)) {
                if (hm.get(email).getPassword().equals(password)) {
                    showMessageDialog(this, "Successfully login");

                    ch = new Chat_Window("lets chat!!");
                    System.out.println("after call");

                } else {
                    showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Password");
                }
            } else {
                showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Login ID and Password");
            }
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("Invalid file");
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
```

why do i get a null pointer exception when i call "ch = new Chat_Window("lets chat!!");"?
Chat_window class is available in the same package and with matching constructor, code is as below:

```
public Chat_Window(String title){
    super(title);
    setSize(500, 500);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    c1=new JPanel();
    c2=new JPanel();
            lbl=new JLabel("Type Here:");
    c1.add(lbl, new GridLayout(1, 2, 50, 50));
    ta=new JTextArea(03,30);
    c1.add(ta,new GridLayout(1, 2, 50, 50) );
    c1.add(send_but,new GridLayout(1, 2, 50, 50));
    add(c1, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    send_but=new JButton("Send");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

}
```

Help please!!!

Comment: It means you get an NPE inside the `Chat_Window` constructor. The NPE should have a line number. What code is on that line?

Comment: The actual stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: ch = new Chat_Window("lets chat!!"); this is the code where i get a NPE

Comment: send_but variable is used before it is initialized

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at swing_frame.Chat_Window.<init>(Chat_Window.java:48)
 at swing_frame.LoginFrame.actionPerformed(LoginFrame.java:139)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 at 
 .

Comment: And what's on line 48 in `ChatWindow`? (Chat_Window.java:48 in the stack trace)

Comment: @oikku   i have provided action listener for the send_button later on in the code.

Comment: @NilsH  on line 48 i am just adding the send_but to the panel created.

Comment: .... and there's your cause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `send_but` before you are creating it.

```
c1.add(send_but,new GridLayout(1, 2, 50, 50));  // send_but is null here
add(c1, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
send_but=new JButton("Send");
```

Comment: Thats it dude!! thanks for the answer. small mistake couldn't recognize.

Comment: @user1740451 If this solved your problem, please mark it as the correct answer.